# Null check operator used on a null value in flutter blog app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, widget

The following _CastError was thrown building Expanded(flex: 1):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Expanded Expanded:file:///home/abdallah/StudioProjects/gei/lib/news_page.dart:45:13

```
Expanded(child: GetBuilder<HomeController>(builder:(value) {
          if(value.newss.isNotEmpty){
            return ListView.builder(

              itemCount: value.newss.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return  Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0,vertical: 5.0),
                child: Post(model: value.newss[index],),
                );
                
              },
            );
          }else{
            return const Center(child: Text("No News Avilable"),);
          }
        },

        ),
        
        )
```

HomeController Code

```
    class HomeController extends GetxController{
  final FirebaseFunctions _functions = FirebaseFunctions();
  final ScrollController controller =  ScrollController();
  List<NewsModel> newss = [];
  var isLoding = false.obs;
  void getData() async{
    newss.addAll(await _functions.getNews());
    update();
  }
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getData();
    controller.addListener(() {
      _functions.isLoading.listen((p) {
        isLoding.value = p;
      });
      double maxScrollPoint = controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
      double currentPosition = controller.position.pixels;
      double height20 = Get.size.height *0.20;
      if(maxScrollPoint - currentPosition <= height20){
        getData();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is hard to tell from your code snippet but I'd have to guess that you are attempting to cast a value that is null to a type that is non-nullable. Perhaps `value` is null but you are trying to cast it to `HomeController`. I do not see any null coercion operators so it must be that line. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the GetBuilder widget to see any more

Comment: @Andrew or maybe the if condition creates that error, where he checks for `value.newss.isNotEmpty` but should maybe check for null first like `if(value != null && value.newss != null && value.newss.isNotEmpty)`

Comment: @AnteBule i tried if(value != null && value.newss != null && value.newss.isNotEmpty) but it didn`t work

Comment: @AbdallahHossam that was my only suspect, like Andrew I am also not familiar with the GetBuilder Widget to say more about it.

Comment: @AnteBule just give me a minute i will edit my question and put HomeController code

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with GetX state management tool yet, but could it be that your null check fails somewhere inside of your `Post` Widget returned from `ListView`'s `itemBuilder`?

Comment: @AnteBule it didn`t work but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<HomeController> homecontroller = value.newss[index]
child: Post(model: homecontroller)
```

Comment: can you describe how I can try this?!

Comment: will you provide the full code?, I will fix it and then post as a answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that because You use the expanded itself did You try to remove it and let me ask did You use it on a row or column

Comment: I use it on a column

Comment: And I don`t think it is because expanded because it was working very good before I added the part of GetBuilder<HomeController>

Comment: What about your post model can you share the code, please

Comment: You didn't provide a specific answer, but instead requested more information. This is better done as a comment to the top-level question where answers provide the person asking the question with a potential solution.